# Don't want to create a new database if it doesn't already exists

Tags: python, sqlite

If I have the following code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('abc.db')
```

.. it will create DB fle called `abc.db` if it doesn't already exist. What do I do if I don't want to create a new file and only want the connection to succeed if the file already exists?

Comment: Check if the file 'abc.db' exists before creating the connection object : `os.path.isfile('abc.db')`

Comment: Thanks. And what if I want the connection to be read-only?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932607/how-to-check-if-a-sqlite3-database-exists-in-python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a SQLite3 database exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932607/how-to-check-if-a-sqlite3-database-exists-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the file already exists or not:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('abc.db'):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('abc.db')
```

Comment: @EugeneGill http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205744/opening-sqlite3-database-from-python-in-read-only-mode

Comment: This solution has a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

Use sqlite3_open_v2() with either SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY or SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE.

As described here:
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: How do you do that in Python?

Comment: Actually this answer is on the right track. It is possible to call the **sqlite_open_v2()** API from Python, albeit indirectly, by using an URI style database identifier passed to **sqlite3.connect()**. For more gory details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47351716/4231304.

Answer (score -2):

you can chill, python doesn't create a new database if it is already existing and connects to the pre-existing one!

works in python 2.7 !

try this:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('path/to/database'):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('abc.db')
else:
    print "Error! db already exists!"
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue. I didn't want to connect to a non-existent database, which causes a new DB to be created,  if didn't already exist.