# Python error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: config

Tags: python, ubuntu, dropbox

I'm need to change the drop box default folder, via command line(because I need to do this in another machine in my local network,so I will access this machine via protocol ssh from the my local machine)to another folder, I search in the Internet and the solution is the same in all the that I find, use this python script:

```
> #!/usr/bin/env  
> # Script for showing or setting the dropbox folder.
> #
> # Execute without options to show current dropbox folder (if non-default).
> # Execute with --setfolder=/foo/bar to set new dropbox folder.
> #
> # I dedicate this work to the public domain by waiving all my rights to the
> # work worldwide under copyright law, including all related and neighboring
> # rights, to the extent allowed by law.
> #
> # You can copy, modify, distribute and perform the work, even for commercial
> # purposes, all without asking permission.
> #
> # Wim Coenen (wcoenen@gmail.com).

import base64
import optparse
import os
import os.path
import sqlite3

# parse command line options
cmdparser = optparse.OptionParser()
cmdparser.add_option("-s","--setfolder", dest="folder",
  help="set dropbox folder")
(options, args) = cmdparser.parse_args()

db_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.dropbox/dropbox.db")
db = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
cursor = db.cursor()

# get dropbox_path
cursor.execute("select value from config where key='dropbox_path'")  
dropbox_path = "<default>"
for entry in cursor:
   dropbox_path_base64 = entry[0]
   dropbox_path_raw = base64.decodestring(dropbox_path_base64)
   dropbox_path = dropbox_path_raw[1:-5]
print "current dropbox path: %s" % dropbox_path

if not options.folder is None:
   new_path_raw = "V" + os.path.abspath(options.folder) + "\np1\n."
   new_path_base64 = base64.encodestring(new_path_raw) 
   cursor.execute("delete from config where key='dropbox_path'")
   cursor.execute("insert into config (key,value) values (?,?)", \
      ("dropbox_path", new_path_base64))
   db.commit()
   print "new dropbox path: %s" % options.folder
   
db.close()
```

here it is the tutorial link what I followed: https://whatbox.ca/wiki/Dropbox

So, I'm very newbie with python, when I try execute this script

```
python ~/Downloads/dropboxdir.py --setfolder=/home/user/new_folder
```

he returnd this error:

> *cursor.execute("select value from config where key='dropbox_path'")*
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: config

So guys, I need a light, any help is welcome.

Comment: You got a database and you run the script on it. And the error reports that the database has no table "config" inside. How can we solve that problem? The problem resides in the database that lacks the required table.

Comment: @aronadaal hmm ,I'm understanding...So what I can do add this table?

Comment: You can add thew table by the create table command but dropbox seems to have chnaged

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva By default if sqlite3 database does not exists in the path it was accessed, a blank db will be created by sqlite3 libraries. Most likely it is the reason why you are looking at error "table does not exists". I suggest to check if DB exists and if yes, use chrome extension of browsing sqlite3 database and check contents of DB manually before accessing it via program.

Comment: @VijayakumarUdupa hmmm...interesting, so how I can check if DB exists exactly? I never work with sqlite3...

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva You can check if file exists using operating system commands. In case of python you can use `os.path.isfile()` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932607/how-to-check-with-python-and-sqlite3-if-one-sqlite-database-file-exists for more comprehensive checks

Answer (score 0):

The database is an internal part of non open source software. I would assume that the developers of Dropbox have chnaged the structure of the database.

In my case using dropbox version v16.4.30 on OSX the dropbox.db file does not even exist so they have changed it even more

Comment: you mean the developers of sqlite3?