# If filename in folder A exists in Database move to folder B, If file does not exist, insert filename into database and move file to folder C

Tags: python

I have 3 Folders

```
Folder A (Landing Folder)
Folder B (Deletion Folder)
Folder C (Transfer to AWS Folder)
```

I've written some python code to move files to the landing folder after some data transformation, from the landing folder - i need to make a decision tree for the files:

```
 Check each filename in folder A to see if it exists in the database
 if the file exists already:
    move the file to Folder B
 Else
 Insert the file name into the Database & move the file to Folder C for transfer to AWS
```

I have the SQL statement inside python tested and working, but im not sure on how to move the files to their respective folders.

I'm assuming that i need something along the lines of using shutil.move to Folder B or C depending on outcome, but not 100% sure on the syntax to get there.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've just edited my answer, hope it will help.

Comment: @MrNobody33 - Yes that answer was great, i can build something from this! Thank you for the assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` to get a list of the files in a given path, and as you said, you can use `shutil.move()` to move the files. So, you could try something like this:

```
import os
import shutil

folderA='pathfolderA'
folderB='pathfolderB'
folderC='pathfolderC'

files=os.listdir(folderA)
for fil in files:
    if fil in database:
        shutil.move(fil,folderB)
    else:
        # insert(fil) into database
        shutil.move(fil,folderC)
```

I'm ignoring the explicity of steps `if fil in database` and `insert(fil) into database`, because you said you have the SQL statement successfully tested. You can chekout the this helpful info about `shutil` and `os.listdir`: [link 1:shutil](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/python-the-shutil-module/), [link 2:shutil](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-create-move-and-delete-files-in-python/), [link 3:shutil](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shutil-move-method/), [link 4:os.listdir](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-listdir-method/).

Comment: @MrNoboddy33 Seems i may have gotten a little ahead of myself - i can do the insert query just fine - but having zero luck with checking if the filename already exists in the database, if you could help with that part, i'd be very grateful

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15355790/13676202). Hope it will help you.